# custom delete button uitableview iphone sdk

Tags: iphone

I wanted swipe a custom view into a UITableViewCell. I can set and use the swipe delete button but I want to have the same effect with any view.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIView *editingAccessoryView
```

of `UITableViewCell`?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try it will Custom cell & each having the UIView in cell.

That would be much easier way to manage if there are multiple view & user will also be able to scroll for all view.

Hope this trick would work .